# No sound from speakers in Ubuntu 22.04 in the Ubuntu installer

Tags: sound, 22.04, alsa

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a new Dell XPS 17 recently. While I get great sound from the built-in speakers in a *Try Ubuntu* session, I lose all sound during a full installation.

I ran some tests in *Try Ubuntu* mode and also during the full installation and found that the sinks listed upon running  `pacmd list-sinks` in the *Try Ubuntu* session do not show up in the full install. Below is the stuff I have tried with the output first in a *Try Ubuntu* session and then in the Ubuntu installer.

Try Ubuntu mode:

```
# ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci -v | grep -A1 -i audio
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 51ca (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Device 0bda
--
Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl

# ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ pacmd list-sinks
5 sink(s) available.
    index: 0
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw.HiFi__hw_sofsoundwire_7__sink>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
state: SUSPENDED
suspend cause: IDLE
priority: 9037
volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
       balance 0.00
base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 0.00 ms
max request: 0 KiB
max rewind: 0 KiB
monitor source: 0
sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
            Stereo
used by: 0
linked by: 0
configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 341.33 ms
card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw>
module: 7
properties:
alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
device.api = "alsa"
device.class = "sound"
alsa.class = "generic"
alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
alsa.name = ""
alsa.id = "HDMI 3 (*)"
alsa.subdevice = "0"
alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
alsa.device = "7"
alsa.card = "0"
alsa.card_name = "sof-soundwire"
alsa.long_card_name = "Intel Soundwire SOF"
alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_sof_sdw"
device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3-platform-sof_sdw"
sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof_sdw/sound/card0"
device.bus = "pci"
device.vendor.id = "8086"
device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
device.product.id = "51ca"
device.string = "_ucm0001.hw:sofsoundwire,7"
device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
device.buffering.fragment_size = "16384"
device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
device.profile.name = "HiFi: hw:sofsoundwire,7: sink"
device.profile.description = "HDMI / DisplayPort 3 Output"
alsa.mixer_device = "_ucm0001.hw:sofsoundwire"
device.description = "sof-soundwire HDMI / DisplayPort 3 Output"
module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
ports:
[Out] HDMI3: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 Output (priority 700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
properties:

active port: <[Out] HDMI3>
    index: 1
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw.HiFi__hw_sofsoundwire_6__sink>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
state: SUSPENDED
suspend cause: IDLE
priority: 9036
volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
       balance 0.00
base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 0.00 ms
max request: 0 KiB
max rewind: 0 KiB
monitor source: 1
sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
            Stereo
used by: 0
linked by: 0
configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 341.33 ms
card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw>
module: 7
properties:
alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
device.api = "alsa"
device.class = "sound"
alsa.class = "generic"
alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
alsa.name = ""
alsa.id = "HDMI 2 (*)"
alsa.subdevice = "0"
alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
alsa.device = "6"
alsa.card = "0"
alsa.card_name = "sof-soundwire"
alsa.long_card_name = "Intel Soundwire SOF"
alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_sof_sdw"
device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3-platform-sof_sdw"
sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof_sdw/sound/card0"
device.bus = "pci"
device.vendor.id = "8086"
device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
device.product.id = "51ca"
device.string = "_ucm0001.hw:sofsoundwire,6"
device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
device.buffering.fragment_size = "16384"
device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
device.profile.name = "HiFi: hw:sofsoundwire,6: sink"
device.profile.description = "HDMI / DisplayPort 2 Output"
alsa.mixer_device = "_ucm0001.hw:sofsoundwire"
device.description = "sof-soundwire HDMI / DisplayPort 2 Output"
module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
ports:
[Out] HDMI2: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 Output (priority 600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
properties:

active port: <[Out] HDMI2>
    index: 2
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw.HiFi__hw_sofsoundwire_5__sink>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
state: SUSPENDED
suspend cause: IDLE
priority: 9035
volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
       balance 0.00
base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 0.00 ms
max request: 0 KiB
max rewind: 0 KiB
monitor source: 2
sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
            Stereo
used by: 0
linked by: 0
configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 341.33 ms
card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw>
module: 7
properties:
alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
device.api = "alsa"
device.class = "sound"
alsa.class = "generic"
alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
alsa.name = ""
alsa.id = "HDMI 1 (*)"
alsa.subdevice = "0"
alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
alsa.device = "5"
alsa.card = "0"
alsa.card_name = "sof-soundwire"
alsa.long_card_name = "Intel Soundwire SOF"
alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_sof_sdw"
device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3-platform-sof_sdw"
sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof_sdw/sound/card0"
device.bus = "pci"
device.vendor.id = "8086"
device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
device.product.id = "51ca"
device.string = "_ucm0001.hw:sofsoundwire,5"
device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
device.buffering.fragment_size = "16384"
device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
device.profile.name = "HiFi: hw:sofsoundwire,5: sink"
device.profile.description = "HDMI / DisplayPort 1 Output"
alsa.mixer_device = "_ucm0001.hw:sofsoundwire"
device.description = "sof-soundwire HDMI / DisplayPort 1 Output"
module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
ports:
[Out] HDMI1: HDMI / DisplayPort 1 Output (priority 500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
properties:

active port: <[Out] HDMI1>
    index: 3
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw.HiFi__hw_sofsoundwire__sink>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
state: SUSPENDED
suspend cause: IDLE
priority: 9032
volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
       balance 0.00
base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 0.00 ms
max request: 0 KiB
max rewind: 0 KiB
monitor source: 3
sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
            Stereo
used by: 0
linked by: 0
configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 341.33 ms
card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw>
module: 7
properties:
alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
device.api = "alsa"
device.class = "sound"
alsa.class = "generic"
alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
alsa.name = ""
alsa.id = "Jack Out (*)"
alsa.subdevice = "0"
alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
alsa.device = "0"
alsa.card = "0"
alsa.card_name = "sof-soundwire"
alsa.long_card_name = "Intel Soundwire SOF"
alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_sof_sdw"
device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3-platform-sof_sdw"
sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof_sdw/sound/card0"
device.bus = "pci"
device.vendor.id = "8086"
device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
device.product.id = "51ca"
device.string = "_ucm0001.hw:sofsoundwire"
device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
device.buffering.fragment_size = "16384"
device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
device.profile.name = "HiFi: hw:sofsoundwire: sink"
device.profile.description = "Headphones"
alsa.mixer_device = "_ucm0001.hw:sofsoundwire"
device.description = "sof-soundwire Headphones"
module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
ports:
[Out] Headphones: Headphones (priority 200, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
properties:

active port: <[Out] Headphones>
  * index: 4
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw.HiFi__hw_sofsoundwire_2__sink>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
state: SUSPENDED
suspend cause: IDLE
priority: 9031
volume: front-left: 45876 /  70% / -9.29 dB,   front-right: 45876 /  70% / -9.29 dB
       balance 0.00
base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 0.00 ms
max request: 0 KiB
max rewind: 0 KiB
monitor source: 4
sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
            Stereo
used by: 0
linked by: 0
configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 341.33 ms
card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw>
module: 7
properties:
alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
device.api = "alsa"
device.class = "sound"
alsa.class = "generic"
alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
alsa.name = ""
alsa.id = "Speaker (*)"
alsa.subdevice = "0"
alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
alsa.device = "2"
alsa.card = "0"
alsa.card_name = "sof-soundwire"
alsa.long_card_name = "Intel Soundwire SOF"
alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_sof_sdw"
device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3-platform-sof_sdw"
sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof_sdw/sound/card0"
device.bus = "pci"
device.vendor.id = "8086"
device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
device.product.id = "51ca"
device.string = "_ucm0001.hw:sofsoundwire,2"
device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
device.buffering.fragment_size = "16384"
device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
device.profile.name = "HiFi: hw:sofsoundwire,2: sink"
device.profile.description = "Speaker"
alsa.mixer_device = "_ucm0001.hw:sofsoundwire"
device.description = "sof-soundwire Speaker"
module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
ports:
[Out] Speaker: Speaker (priority 100, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
properties:

active port: <[Out] Speaker>
```

The following code detected the following devices:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 51ca (rev 01)
```

The following terminal command generated a list of playback devices as follows:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 0: Jack Out (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 2: Speaker (*) []
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 5: HDMI 1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 6: HDMI 2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 7: HDMI 3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Upon full installation:

```
jammy@m1m:~$ lspci -v | grep -A1 -i audio
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 51ca (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0bda
--
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
```

```
jammy@m1m:~$ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 57672 /  88% / -3.33 dB,   front-right: 57672 /  88% / -3.33 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.23 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 2.51 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    module: 14
    properties:
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

As you can see the sinks were not detected during a full installation.

Comment: Usually, new versions of ubuntu have better support for very recent hardware. Give Ubuntu 23.10 a try, and let us know if it works

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi : Thanks for your inputs. Running 23.10 and everything works beautifully!